# How to fix `Compilation failure` about javac parameter `--add-exports` in maven3

Tags: java, maven, java-module, maven-compiler-plugin

My code contains the `sun.misc.SharedSecrets` class and the `sun.nio.ch.Interruptible` class, I want them to work in java modular maven.

The code is running in Java 11, maven 3.6.1, and the `maven-compiler-plugin` version is 3.8.1.

The configuration of `maven-compiler-plugin` is:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>11</source>
        <target>11</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>--add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.misc=cn.piumnl.learning.java.interrupt</arg>
            <arg>--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=cn.piumnl.learning.java.interrupt</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and run `maven package -X`, output error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project concurrent: Fatal error compiling: 错误: 无效的标记: --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.misc=cn.piumnl.learning.java.interrupt -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project concurrent: Fatal error compiling
```

I guess because the version of javac when maven is compiled is too low. so I update the configuration of `maven-compiler-plugin`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>11</source>
        <target>11</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>

        <!-- update -->
        <verbose>false</verbose>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\javac</executable>
        <compilerVersion>11</compilerVersion>
        <!-- update -->

        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>--add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.misc=cn.piumnl.learning.java.interrupt</arg>
            <arg>--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=cn.piumnl.learning.java.interrupt</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and run `maven package -X` against, output error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project concurrent: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project concurrent: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1224)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:187)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

This time maven did not provide more useful information. Is `maven-compiler-plugin` not support `--add-exports`?

Or is there any other way to get parameters `--add-exports` to javac when maven compiles?

Comment: Classes like `sun.misc*` are part of the JDK8 you should never use `sun.*` within your code and I don't understand `sun.nio.ch.Interruptible` Why have you named them like this? Apart from that your code does not compile: `..Fatal error compiling`...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you for your reply, you reminded me that `SharedSecrets` should be under the `jdk.internal.misc` package instead of `sun.misc`, following this idea I solved this problem. Then I explain to you my behavior. First of all, I know that these classes should not be used, but my code is just for learning and will not be used in a formal environment, I want to make them work in later versions of jdk8. Secondly, if the compilation fails normally, there will be prompt information, such as missing semicolons, no classes, etc., instead of only one error message that failed to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this question, I made three mistakes.

1. In JDK8 `SharedSecrets` full name is `sun.misc.SharedSecrets`, but in JDK9 later is `jdk.internal.misc.SharedSecrets`.
2. the other is `maven-compiler-plugin`, `<compilerArgs></compilerArgs>` only one parameter is supported. It has to be changed `<compilerArgs><arg></arg></compilerArgs>`.
3. The compilation parameter should be `--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=<you moudle>` instead of `--add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.misc=<you moudle>`

Finally the configuration of maven should be like this：

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>11</source>
        <target>11</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>

        <!-- update -->
        <verbose>false</verbose>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\javac</executable>
        <compilerVersion>11</compilerVersion>
        <!-- update -->

        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=cn.piumnl.learning.java.interrupt</arg>
            <arg>--add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=cn.piumnl.learning.java.interrupt</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```